# How to connect to internet through raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, debian

Here i have connected my raspberry pi to my laptop using the ethernet cable.
Inside the raspberry pi boot SD card i have opened the file cmdline and added the following information at the end of the file.

```
ip=169.254.1.1
```

Now i have connected my raspberry pi to the laptop using the ethernet cable and used putty to connect to this device by using the ip address 169.254.1.1 and port 22 using SSH.

Everything is working fine , i have accesed the file system.
But now i wanted to access the intenet so i have entered the command

```
ping 8.8.8.8
connect:Network in unreachable
```

How to access to the internet?How to approach this problem?Any suggestions.

Tutorial followed : [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ioih6MHNNqc)

Comment: What OS is your laptop using?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming Your desktop is running a Windows system)

It seems that the raspberry in question doesn't have Internet access, yet.

Ethernet-connecting raspberry to a laptop that already has Internet access doesn't necessarily mean it will get Internet from the laptop. For that to happen, You also need to allow Internet forwarding in connection options of Your network adapter settings.

ENABLING WI-FI INTERNET OVER ETHERNET CABLE:
[How can I share a laptop's Wi-Fi connection through its Ethernet port?](https://superuser.com/questions/86626/how-can-i-share-a-laptops-wi-fi-connection-through-its-ethernet-port#86633)

Another option is to connect raspberry to the Internet using an in-build (raspberry3) Wi-Fi or usb-slot-wifi-card.
Try googling Connecting to wifi network through command line,
or follow this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/167425/how-to-setup-wi-fi-on-your-raspberry-pi-via-the-command-line/